# Intercept calls from Oracle Data Provider to the database

Tags: oracle, odp

Is there a way to intercept calls from Oracle Data Provider to the database? I would like to see which procedures are being called and which parameters they are receiving.

I tried with DBMS_MONITOR.DATABASE_TRACE_ENABLE, and then checking the trace files with tkprof, but I can't find the procedure parameter info, it seemes like this is just query related.

Logging inside the procedure is not really an option. In fact I'm trying to log when a procedure is called with a wrong parameter list (and no executed)

If you can point me into the right direction (oracle documentation or anything) I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

" In fact I'm trying to log when a procedure is called with a wrong parameter list (and no executed)"

Does it error ? If so, look at the SERVERERROR trigger which can catch the problem SQL.

You should be able to see it in the raw trace file. However TKPROF would filter it out as it is a primarily providing a view of profiling/tuning data.